# How do I dim other elements in the webpage when I click on that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am building a wordpress website and in the header part there is a search bar. How to create a `dim effect(background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3))` on other elements except in search bar when I use the search bar (for example like in Quora.com). Also this code(your answer) should be working if I use code for other elements(other than search bar) like input box,or any other div.

I will be more satisfied if you come with an answer that is flexible to use for any div.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: `I will be more satisfied if you come with an answer that is flexible to use for any div.` You seem to have confused StackOverflow with a code writing service.

Comment: What is really StackOverflow?

Comment: Adding on to Rory's comment - have you tried something and it didn't quite work? could you include that so that we can have a look at what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a click event to the element that needs to be clicked. You can then bind a function to that event that is triggered upon the click, as follows:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", changeColour);

function changeColour() {
  var changeme = document.getElementById("change");
  changeme.classList.add("addopacity");
}
```

```css
#change {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#change.addopacity {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Click me please</button>
<div id="change"></div>
```

Please note, you don't have to add a class to the target element like I have above, you can just as easily add an inline style with `changeme.style.opacity = "0.2";` within the function.

If you want to click on the element itself and have it change colour, you can do something similar:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("change");
test.addEventListener("click", changeColour);

function changeColour() {
  this.classList.add("addopacity");
}
```

```css
#change {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
#change.addopacity {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="change">CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `opacity` [property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) and apply it wherever you need it.

```
div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: How to sense the click and change opacity accordingly?

Comment: @codewiz You add an event that, when triggered, applies a CSS "opacity" class to whatever elements you need to be transparent. Learn about [JavaScript events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) and [how to apply CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) using JavaScript.